# No overload for matches delegate 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler'

Tags: c#

I was reading this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/
So playing with the windows services I encountered a little problem due to my lack of knowledge. In this part of the code:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 10800; 
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick()
    {
       //some code here
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
      //some code here

    }
```

The             `this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);`
gives:

> Error 1   No overload for 'timer1_Tick' matches delegate
>   'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler'

I wonder why since many people don't have a problem with that example?

Comment: The signature should be `private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)`, like most event handlers.

Comment: @minitech: instead of EventArgs you might want to use ElapsedEventArgs.

Comment: Or you have made a typo in copying the example or the example is not correct. [Checked, you have made a typo]

Comment: thank you both, i gave credit to the most complete answer, but thank you both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An event is nothing else as a multicast delegate. And your method signature does not match the delegate signature, in your case the `ElapsedEventHandler` delegate.

You have to change your code:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    this.timer1.Interval = 10800; 
    this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArg)
{
   //some code here
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
  //some code here

}
```

You could also instead of:

```
this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
```

Do this:

```
timer.Elapsed += this.timer1_Tick;
```

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArg) did it. Thank you.

Comment: In my situation I used an uppercase "O" in Object. Changed it lowercase and it works.